# Tie Successful Release To Gated Check-In?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

With the new VSTS build system is it possible to require a successful release of a build (to CI) before accepting a gated check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gated check-in only tie with successful build not release so far. But there still other options to handle the situation.

I posted a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18483310-gated-check-in-both-tie-with-successful-build-and), you can vote it up.

**Option1:** manually call a release and add the result in your build. You can add a power shell task in your build definition which run the release, and then obtain the release result, if the release is failed you can make your build fail.

**Option2:** Even the release is failed, It’s also accept to check in. So you can use [rollback with release management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/28/implement-rollback-with-release-management-for-tfs-2015/).